# LWJGL/OpenGL How do I resize my image in order to fit my sphere?

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

I am working on a project and I tried to wrap an image around my shape, specifically a sphere. The problem is that the image does cover most of the sphere, only parts. How can I resize my image to where it fits the whole sphere perfectly?

```
import java.io.IOException;
import org.lwjgl.*;
import org.lwjgl.input.Keyboard;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.*;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.EXTFramebufferObject.glGenerateMipmapEXT;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.*;
import static org.lwjgl.util.glu.GLU.gluPerspective;
import org.lwjgl.util.glu.Sphere;
import org.newdawn.slick.opengl.*;
import org.newdawn.slick.util.ResourceLoader;

private void render() {
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glLoadIdentity();

    glTranslatef(0, 0, -8);
    glRotatef(rotateAngle, 0, 1, 0);
    Sphere s = new Sphere();
    s.setNormals(GL_SMOOTH);
    s.setTextureFlag(true);
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glGenerateMipmapEXT(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, t.getTextureID());
    s.draw(3, 64, 64);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your texture should already cover the whole sphere, based on the documentation I found for the LWJGL `Sphere` class. One problem in your code is that you set some texture attributes before binding the texture. You'll want to move the `glBindTexture` call before `glGenerateMipmapEXT()` and `glTexParamteri` calls.

To control the scaling of the texture with the fixed OpenGL pipeline, you can apply transformations to the texture coordinates by setting the matrix mode to `GL_TEXTURE`. For example, to make the texture larger, try:

```
glMatrixMode(GL_TEXTURE);
glLoadIdentity();
glScalef(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f);
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
```

By dividing the texture coordinates by a factor 2, you will make the texture image appear twice as large.

Comment: That was not the problem. Apparently the dimensions of the image must be in the power of 2, for example 128x128 or 512x64. Thank you for the help anyways.

Answer (score 0):

In order for the whole image to cover the shape, the texture must be in a dimension in the power of 2, for example 32x1024 or 128x128.

Comment: That depends on the underlying OpenGL version. Non-power of 2 textures have been fully supported since OpenGL 3.0. So if you're using any moderately recent OpenGL version, you should not have that restriction.